# Nodal analysis on transformers

Tags: circuit-analysis, transformer, nodal-analysis

On the middle circuit(with the V1), can I do nodal analysis to get the voltages? Or not necessarily do it since the voltage is parallel to the each side of the circuit?
I will refer the V2 side to the left side of the transformer.

[image]

Comment: "middle transformer"? I can only see two.

Comment: @Finbarr my bad, it’s supposed to be circuit

Comment: *can I do nodal analysis to get the voltages?* <-- yes you can.